# What does ServicePointManager.SecurityProtoco value of zero mean?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

What does a ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol value of 0 actually mean?

What protocol will be used for an https connection if this has a value of zero?

I ask because `Enum.TryParse<System.Net.SecurityProtocolType>("arg", out protocol)` returns value of protocol=0 if "arg" is not a valid string (eg "Tls12" etc), but the documentation in msdn is a bit vague about the consequences.

TIA

Comment: None, it's not a valid value for SecurityProtocolType, not sure but the most probable is it throws an exception when you try to use it.

Comment: That's the puzzle - it doesn't throw an exception. If I create a secure connection to a mail server that insists on TLS (eg gmail.com) using a protocol value of 0, I can successfully send an email on that connection.

Comment: wow... hmmm maybe you can see how Mono implemented it? you can go to the git mono source and peek a look, it can give you an idea on how it works.

Comment: Thanks, worth a try but that assumes Mono does exactly the same as 'official' .Net. I'm thinking that maybe .Net takes 0 to mean "whatever you can negotiate", but I was hoping someone in the know would be able to clear it up for me.

Comment: .net has open sourced also a ton of the .net framework: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ check if it's there.

Comment: I'd like to know an answer to this question too. Currently we are upgrading our infrastructure to only support TLS1.2. Some of our client applications are compiled in older frameworks that default to older security protocols (I believe .NET 3.5 defaults to SSL3+TLS1.0). Our server gurus installed some kind of patch that changes that default to TLS1.2. This way we don't need to upgrade every single application to use TLS1.2. However, when I read this "patched" protocol value, it actually comes as zero and not 3072 (TLS1.2 value). And yet it works. I'd like to know why.